# ProcessStartInfo fails to start Office apps with other system user

Tags: c#, windows

Trying to launch Office apps with other user on the system is not working, it is throwing this exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

It is working properly for other win32 apps like Notepad, etc..

This is the code snippet:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var processPath = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"; // Path to a local office app
    ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(processPath)
    {
        UserName = "otherUserInTheSystemName",
        Domain = Environment.MachineName,
        Password = StringToSecureString("password"),
        LoadUserProfile = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\users\otherUserInTheSystemName"
    };
    Process.Start(ps);
}

private static SecureString StringToSecureString(string value)
{
    var password = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        password.AppendChar(c);
    }
    return password;
}
}
```

Tested under Windows 10 2004 (OS Build 19041.508)

Comment: Is this running in IIS?  Windows Service?

Comment: no, it is not running in IIS

Comment: Is there actually a user session with that user? I'm pretty sure Office requires there to be an actual user session, you can't just impersonate another user. By the way, running Office out of IIS is very much unsupported; it might be a good idea to try another approach to your problem entirely.

Comment: this was working fine before Windows update to 2004, ProcessStartInfo was able to launch Office apps under other system user account without issues

Comment: *"It used to work"* isn't testament that the code was intrinsically correct.

Comment: @IInspectable then tell me why the code is not correct

Comment: I don't know what's wrong since I cannot see vital parts of the code. Show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable edited to show the minimal reproducible example

Comment: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) - "Office applications assume that they are being run under an interactive desktop". Notepad is a bad program to try to draw general conclusions from because of how *basic* it is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it happens on an interactive desktop :)

Comment: This isn't complete. We cannot see your P/Invoke declarations. Those are commonly wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable this is complete, I'm not using pinvoke declarations. I'm using ProcessStartInfo and Process from .Net framework:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.6.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.6.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_

Comment: The error diagnostic is telling you what's wrong. You can only launch Excel into an interactive user session. A restriction that has always existed. Who knows, maybe the system update started to enforce this restriction.